# Different behaviour when using constant string versus reading data from a file

Tags: perl

I'm having trouble reading a UTF-8 file and detecting some non-ASCII characters like 'á' or 'ö'.  If I simply declare a constant string with the UTF-8 characters, everything works fine, the error only occurs on file contents.

My input file looks like:

```
áéíóúöüőűÁÉÍÓÚÖÜŐŰäÄß
```

My perl program looks:

```
use utf8;    
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";    
my $szo = "áéíóúöüőűÁÉÍÓÚÖÜŐŰäÄß";    
list($szo);

while(<STDIN>){
chomp;
list($_);
}

sub list($){
  my ($szo) = @_;

  my @arr = split(//, $szo);
  foreach(@arr){
     my $ord = ord($_);
     if($_ eq 'á'){print "á\n";}
     print "isoe elem:$_ ord:$ord \n"; 
  }
}
```

The execution results in the following output:

```
á  
isoe elem:á ord:225   
isoe elem:é ord:233   
isoe elem:í ord:237   
isoe elem:ó ord:243   
....    
isoe elem:ß ord:223   
From here file data, no good:  
isoe elem:Ã ord:195   
isoe elem:¡ ord:161   
isoe elem:Ã ord:195   
isoe elem:© ord:169   
...    
isoe elem:Ã ord:195   
isoe elem: ord:159
```

Comment: Set the file handle you read from to UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks, in the future I will use utf8 also for files.

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify UTF-8 encoding also for `STDIN`, just as you did for `STDOUT`.

Comment: Thank you, adding this: binmode STDIN, ":utf8"; solved the problem.